# Ask to join in Google meet Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-api-python-client

i am working on a an api project

there is a part in it which takes input from the user about Google meeting code and enter him to the google meeting

**the real problem is when i give it instructions to click on the button of `Ask to join`**

i have tried this :

```
1.        driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//button[text()='Ask to join']").click()
2.        driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/span/span').click()
3.        i also tried using class name
```

**every method best to my knowledge I have used them**

also i cannot find help on this topic anywhere

i am banging my head on this piece from last 2 days but cannot find a solution to it

if anyone can help !!
please tell if i should include anything else for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below XPath.

```
//div[@role='button']//span[contains(text(), 'Ask to join')]
```

Comment: element click intercepted: Element <span class="NPEfkd RveJvd snByac">...</span> is not clickable at point (1051, 461). Other element would receive the click: <div class="Sla0Yd">...</div>

Comment: idk whats going on with this @cs95

Comment: @shyam_gupta : You are seeing this error with other element. Please use unique XPath as mentioned in answer and apply proper wait if the page loads on any event.