# unable to click on 'Ask to join' in google meet using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-meet

I have tried many ways to click on 'Ask to join' button on google meet using selenium. Here are some ways i already tried if you know any other way please help me out.
[tried 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64793334/join-google-meet-meetings-automatically)
[tried 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63752334/ask-to-join-in-google-meet-selenium)
[tried 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63873200/how-to-click-on-the-ask-to-join-button-within-https-meet-google-com-using-sele/63873562#63873562)

code snippet that i already tried:

```py
    btn = browser.find_element((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Ask to join')]"))

    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
```

```py
try:
    join_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 36).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Join now')]")))
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", join_button)
except TimeoutException:
    try:
        join_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 36).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Ask to join')]")))
        browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", join_button)
    except TimeoutException:
            print("Couldn't join Google Meet. Are you sure you have the right code?")
```

```py
join_butt = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Ask to join')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", join_butt)
```

thanks in advance!!!!!!

Comment: Have you tried locating the element just by its class name?

Comment: Include the html element and if it's any iframes.

Comment: @HelloWorld i have tried using the class name but it say unable to locate element. 'Ask to join' button is dynamically generated that way the class throw this error.

Comment: @arundeepchohan yes i have tried using html but no luck with that.

Comment: I don't think you have tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63873200/how-to-click-on-the-ask-to-join-button-within-https-meet-google-com-using-sele?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @HelloWorld Yes i have tried that too you can see that in the question (last code). it throw a Timeoutexceptions and i dont know to handle that.